# Appending Dependencies from Another Configuration

Tags: java, gradle

My project is a Java project following standard convention (src/main, src/test ..). I'm trying to write a simple Gradle task the will emit two jar files:

- The "default" jar emitted by Gradle containing my app code
- A jar containing just test classes and dependencies needed to run them (e.g. Junit). This jar should not contain dependencies that are only needed by the non-test code (e.g. Guava in example below).

I tried to use "testCompile" in my testJar task below, but that also picks up non-test Jars. So I created a separate configuration listing just the test dependencies, but now as I would expect tests can't be compiled since the 'testCompile' configuration is not correctly populated.

I haven't seen a way in the DependencyHandler API (which with my limited knowledge of Gradle is what defines the DSL in the dependencies block) to assign one configuration to another. ***How I can add testJars dependency set to testCompile set (not replace) so everything "works"?*** I've placed a comment in my code below where I assume the missing gap is but I might be wrong!

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    testJars
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '14.0.1'
    testJars group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    //"testCompile append testJars"??
}

task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
    from { configurations.testJars.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but adding this to your `configurations` block might accomplish it: `testCompile { extendsFrom testJars }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the custom `testJars` configuration is meant to be a subset of the built-in `testCompile` configuration, you should be able to change your `configurations` block to this:

```
configurations {
    testJars
    testCompile {
        extendsFrom testJars
    }
}
```

Which will augment `testCompile` to include everything that `testJars` has. I think that would give you the classpath you need for compiling test code.